# What is this bolt in my basement floor?

Tags: basement, bolts

In my concrete basement floor, there is a rather large bolt and washer.  The washer is about 4 inches in diameter, and the bolt has a 1 inch head.  What is it?

[image]

All I can think of is that it's some device to keep this from happening:

[image]

Comment: Avoid covering the cleanout when putting down flooring.  You'd hate to have to pull up a floor just to unclog a drain.

Comment: Yeah, I would have had to grind it down to get a tile over it.  It's going to be covered with cabinetry anyway.

Comment: Provide access for your plumber or at least note the location in permanent marker inside the cabinet.  This will minimize the damage if you ever need to unclog something.

Comment: Also, building codes may prohibit covering the access.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

That's likely a cleanout for your sewer line. When opened, you can run an snake down the line to remove any blockage without ripping out your entire foundation. Here's what it would look like from the side:

[image: outdoor side view]

And the cap itself can have different styles:

[image: cap]

Comment: Your answer is likely correct, but I prefer my hypothesis.

Comment: @chris So do I, the movie was pretty awsome which makes up for the real life answer being so mundane.